# Can we have more than 1 Sköll boots?

Tags: runescape

I was wondering if we could have more than 1 pair of Sköll boots or can we recharge it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a second pair of Sköll boots. I tested that you cannot get two at the same time by participating in two Sköll kills. After the first kill I got a pair of boots and after the second kill I did not. [Tip.it](http://open.tip.it/items/view/11999-skoll-boots) confirms that you can only get one pair and implies that they cannot be recharged.